# JCrop: Prevent de-selection?

Tags: jquery, image-processing, jcrop

I'm currently setting up an image-upload cropping sequence.

The application requires an *enforced minimum size*, however this results in awkward JCrop behavior:

- Clicking without dragging produces nothing.
- Clicking & slightly dragging produces instantly a selection of the minimum height.

One potential solution would solve the above problems:

- Interface opens with a default selection.
- The selection cannot be de-selected.

JCrop has built-in functionality for a default selection, however I haven't yet identified a built-in configuration / behavior to prevent deselection.

**Attempts so far -**

I've tried this route

```
$.Jcrop.defaults.onRelease = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I've also tried modifying the plugin's source in several places, in order to short-circuit the functions which (perhaps) carry out the de-selection, by `return`ing at the opening of these function definitions:

`doneSelect`
`Selection.release`
`Selection.done`

...without the desired result.

Any tips?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I wasn't able to find a feasible modification for jCrop to prevent de-selection, I went with the [YUI ImageCropper](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/index.html) instead, which ships with both of the necessary features.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 23):

Set allowSelect: false, for details check: https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/5#issuecomment-1801926.

Answer (score 1):

`allowSelect` option is available now

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on GitHub and it helps.

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    onSelect : updateCoords,
                bgColor : 'transparent',
                bgOpacity : .2,
                setSelect : [ 0, 0, 700, 300 ],
                minSize : [700, 300],
                allowSelect : false,
                onRelease : releaseCheck
                });
        });

function releaseCheck() {
    this.setOptions({ setSelect: [0,0,700,300] });
}
```

https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/5#issuecomment-1801926